# differentiating between post requests

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this jquery function which sends a POST request to the server

```
function loadInfo() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/admin.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    setMarker(data, i, "red");
                    printInfo(data, i);
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

This is how the request gets handled

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require 'private/database.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $data = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
}
```

The code works, but what if I have send multiple POST requests to the same server? Is there a way to differentiate between them like how you would when handling HTML forms?
e.g. If the of the button that submits the form is "submit_button"...

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: So why do you not make different end points to hit if it matters what is submitting it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to send post by AJAX with data (multiple data items). One of the ways is:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {status: "ok", name: "Richard"},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('success');
                } 
})
```

In the above case, you have sent status and name data to the php script by POST method. Hope that it can answer your question.

Comment: When receiving the form, would I use "if (isset($_POST['Richard'])) {}"?

Comment: should be if (isset($_POST['name']))  {  }

Answer (score 1):

You have to send some parameter to differentiate the request.

```
eg:     $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm", method:"formSubmit" } );
```